# Use tag <mark> between string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable `searchString` with contain String.
i have to a list of `titles` what i want filter by `searchString`.
i try to use tag `<mark>` for highlight a piece of title, but can`t do it yet.

I try to implement a funciton that have 2 args and return a jsx for the render.

```
const markString = (title, searchString) => {
  var regex = new RegExp(searchString, 'i');
  const newString = string.replace(regex, '<mark>Banana</mark>');
  console.log(newString);
  return (newString);
};
```

Situation.
`searchString = ab`
`title = abracadabra`

i want the function return something like.
`<mark>ab</mark>racad<mark>ab</mark>ra`

i need a jsx with a string and the tag mark between the world.

someone can help me?

Comment: Your question is unclear what is the problem. What is not working. and where is `titles`?

Comment: Situation. searchString = ab title = abracadabra

i want the function return something like. <mark>ab</mark>racad<mark>ab</mark>ra, tks for your atention

Comment: I have answered the question if you need anymore help ask me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `split()` and `join()`

You can `split()` by title and `join()` by extra `<mark>` tags.

```js
let str = 'abracadabra';

function markString(title, searchString){
  return searchString.split(title).join(`<mark>${title}</mark>`);
}
console.log(markString('ab',str))
```

#### Using RegExp

```js
let str = 'abracadabra';

function markString(title, searchString){
  return searchString.replace(new RegExp(title,"g"),`<mark>${title}</mark>`)
}
console.log(markString('ab',str))
```

Comment: you solution work well, but its return a string, and i need the browser understand tag `mark` but its just render a string `<mark>ab</mark>racad<mark>ab</mark>ra
`, tks